# Do some programs not accept process substitution for input files?

Tags: bash, unix, ipc, process-substitution

I'm trying to use process substitution for an input file to a program, and it isn't working. Is it because some programs don't allow process substitution for input files?

The following doesn't work:

```
bash -c "cat meaningless_name"
    >sequence1
    gattacagattacagattacagattacagattacagattacagattacagattaca
    >sequence2
    gattacagattacagattacagattacagattacagattacagattacagattaca
bash -c "clustalw -align -infile=<(cat meaningless_name) -outfile=output_alignment.aln -newtree=output_tree.dnd"
    (Less verbose output, finishing with:
    No sequences in file. No alignment!
```

But the following controls do work:

```
bash -c "clustalw -align -infile=meaningless_name -outfile=output_alignment.aln -newtree=output_tree.dnd"
    (Verbose output, finishing with:
    CLUSTAL-Alignment file created  [output_alignment.aln]
bash -c "cat <(cat meaningless_name) > meaningless_name2"
diff meaningless_name meaningless_name2
    (No output: the two files are the same)
bash -c "clustalw -align -infile=meaningless_name2 -outfile=output_alignment.aln -newtree=output_tree.dnd"
    (Verbose output, finishing with:
    CLUSTAL-Alignment file created  [output_alignment.aln]
```

Which suggest that process substitution itself works, but that the clustalw program itself doesn't like process substitution - perhaps because it creates a non-standard file, or creates files with an unusual filename.

Is it common for programs to not accept process substitution? How would I check whether this is the issue?

I'm running GNU bash version 4.0.33(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) on Ubuntu 9.10. Clustalw is version 2.0.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  I've noticed the same thing in other programs.  For instance, it doesn't work in emacs either.  It gives "File exists but can not be read".  And it's definitely a special file, for me `/proc/self/fd/some_number`.  And it doesn't work *reliably* in either `less` nor `most`, with default settings.

For most:

```
most <(/bin/echo 'abcdef')
```

and shorter displays nothing.  Longer values truncate the beginning.  `less` apparently works, but only if you specify `-f`.

I find zsh's `=` much more useful in practice.  It's syntactically the same, except `=` instead of `<`.  But it just creates a temporary file, so support doesn't depend on the program.

EDIT:

I found zsh uses `TMPPREFIX` to choose the temporary filename.  So even if you don't want your real `/tmp` to be [`tmpfs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs#Linux), you can mount one for zsh.

Comment: Is the temporary file a file on the hard drive, or in RAM only? I was hoping to avoid hitting the hard drive.

Comment: For me it's `/tmp/zshXXX`.  So you could use [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) pretty easily.

Comment: The [ *zsh* process substitution documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#SEC67) details some of the problems programs might encounter when using the `<()` form of process redirection: expecting lseek(2) to work, closing fds before processing arguments (a possible security feature), hung sub-processes if the command never reads the substituted fd. The first seems like the most likely for the case of this question.

Comment: The computer doesn't have zsh (I'm planning on writing the files I'm using in `/dev/shm` instead), but for the benefit of other people in my situation: is there a risk that if I modify [TMPPREFIX](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#SEC98) it'll change where all new temporary files are kept, not just the ones created using `=(echo 'foo')`?

Comment: @Andrew, the docs say it's used by zsh (not other programs) for all temporary files.  I don't know off hand any other cases when zsh will use such files.

Answer (score 8):

Process substitution creates a named pipe. You can't seek into a named pipe.