# Bash process substitution and syncing

Tags: bash, process-substitution

(Possibly related to [Do some programs not accept process substitution for input files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274171/do-some-programs-not-accept-process-substitution-for-input-files))

In some Bash unit test scripts I'm using the following trick to log *and* display stdout and stderr of a command:

```
command > >(tee "${stdoutF}") 2> >(tee "${stderrF}" >&2)
```

This process produces some output to stdout, so the `$stdoutF` file gets some data. Then I run another command which does not output any data:

```
diff -r "$source" "$target" > >(tee "${stdoutF}") 2> >(tee "${stderrF}" >&2)
```

However, it doesn't look like this process always finishes successfully before the test for emptiness is run (using [shunit-ng](https://github.com/l0b0/shunit-ng)):

```
assertNull 'Unexpected output to stdout' "$(<"$stdoutF")"
```

In a 100 run test this failed 25 times.

Should it be sufficient to call `sync` before testing the file for emptiness:

```
sync
assertNull 'Unexpected output to stdout' "$(<"$stdoutF")"
```

... and/or should it work by forcing the sequence of the commands:

```
diff -r "$source" "$target" \
> >(tee "${stdoutF}"; assertNull 'Unexpected output to stdout' "$(<"$stdoutF")")
2> >(tee "${stderrF}" >&2)
```

... and/or is it possible to `tee` it somehow to `assertNull` directly instead of a file?

**Update**: `sync` is not the answer - See Gilles' response below.

**Update 2**: Discussion taken further to [Save stdout, stderr and stdout+stderr synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497817/save-stdout-stderr-and-stdoutstderr-synchronously). Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In bash, a process substitution substitution command `foo > >(bar)` finishes as soon as `foo` finishes. (This is not discussed in the documentation.) You can check this with

```
: > >(sleep 1; echo a)
```

This command returns immediately, then prints `a` asynchronously one second later.

In your case, the `tee` command takes just one little bit of time to finish after `command` completes. Adding `sync` gave `tee` enough time to complete, but this doesn't remove the race condition, any more than adding a `sleep` would, it just makes the race more unlikely to manifest.

More generally, `sync` does not have any internally observable effect: it only makes a difference if you want to access device where your filesystems are stored under a different operating system instance. In clearer terms, if your system loses power, only data written before the last `sync` is guaranteed to be available after you reboot.

As for removing the race condition, here are a few of possible approaches:

- Explicitly synchronize all substituted processes.

  ```
  mkfifo sync.pipe
  command > >(tee -- "$stdoutF"; echo >sync.pipe)
         2> >(tee -- "$stderrF"; echo >sync.pipe)
  read line < sync.pipe; read line < sync.pipe
  ```
- Use a different temporary file name for each command instead of reusing `$stdoutF` and `$stderrF`, and enforce that the temporary file is always newly created.
- Give up on process substitution and use pipes instead.

  ```
  { { command | tee -- "$stdoutF" 1>&3; } 2>&1 \
              | tee -- "$stderrF" 1>&2; } 3>&1
  ```

  If you need the command's return status, bash puts it in `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`.

  ```
  { { command | tee -- "$stdoutF" 1>&3; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}; } 2>&1 \
              | tee -- "$stderrF" 1>&2; } 3>&1
  if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0 ]; then echo command failed; fi
  ```

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer, this has just made me a better admin!

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes put a guard:

```
: > >(sleep 1; echo a; touch guard) \
  && while true; do
    [ -f "guard" ] && { rm guard; break; }
     sleep 0.2
  done
```

Answer (score -1):

Insert a `sleep 5` or whatnot in place of `sync` to answer your last question