# How to sed on stderr on the fly?

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to process `STDERR` with `sed` on the fly

A program gives me wrong information on `STDERR`, my goal is to correct that information.

So far I have tried this:

```
$ perl -e 'print STDERR "bar says that foo has to disappear"' 2> >(sed s/foo/.../)
```

Unfortunately, something weird happened, the output I get is this:

```
$ perl -e 'print STDERR "bar says that foo has to disappear"' 2> >(sed s/foo/.../)
$ bar says that ... has to disappear
```

You can notice my prompt is printed before the output. How to correct this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4489139/1030675

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try an alternative way by using unnamed pipe:

```
( perl -e 'print STDERR "bar says that foo has to disappear"' 3>&1 1>&2- 2>&3- ) | sed 's/foo/.../g'
```

Prints the output before the prompt for me.