# How to print number of lines of command output in UNIX shell

Tags: shell, unix, numbers, tee, wc

Let's assume that command1 is processing something and I am interested in BOTH output of command1 as well as how many lines the output actually had.

```
$ command1 | wc - l
```

prints number of lines of output of command1, while

```
$ command1 | nl
```

prints something like that:

```
 1  ./PaDe014
 2  ./PaDe033
 3  ./PaDe001
 4  ./PaDe013
 5  ./PaDe025
 6  ./PaDe028
```

See [How to count lines in a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137094/how-to-count-lines-in-a-document) for more solutions.

**However I am interested to generate output like that:**

```
 ./PaDe014
 ./PaDe033
 ./PaDe001
 ./PaDe013
 ./PaDe025
 ./PaDe028

Total number of files generated: 6
```

I have a vague feeling that it can be achieved with `tee` and `wc`, but cannot figure out how exactly.

**What is the simplest way to achieve desired output?**

I also tried:

```
command1 | tee >(wc -l)
```

but there must be a race condition here, as from time to time I receive strange results. Here is the test output:

```
pdebski@PaDe:~$ (ls -l ; printf "Total: ") | tee -a >(wc -l)
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 7 pdebski pdebski 4096 cze 22 18:50 Data
drwxr-xr-x 2 pdebski pdebski 4096 cze 22 15:14 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 pdebski pdebski 4096 cze 22 14:50 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 2 pdebski pdebski 4096 cze 16 01:09 Downloads
-rw-r--r-- 1 pdebski pdebski 8980 cze 16 01:04 examples.desktop
drwxr-xr-x 4 pdebski pdebski 4096 cze 17 13:44 Music
drwxr-xr-x 2 pdebski pdebski 4096 cze 22 13:14 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 pdebski pdebski 4096 cze 16 01:09 Public
drwxr-xr-x 2 pdebski pdebski 4096 cze 16 01:09 Templates
drwxrwxr-x 2 pdebski pdebski 4096 cze 22 01:21 test
drwxrwxr-x 2 pdebski pdebski 4096 cze 22 01:21 test2
drwxr-xr-x 2 pdebski pdebski 4096 cze 16 01:09 Videos
Total: pdebski@PaDe:~$ 13
```

A nice illustration for the need of Dijkstra's Semaphores and Mutexes, is not it? (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra )

Apparently there should be some `wait` here.

Same results with:

```
$ (ls -l && printf "Total: ") | tee -a >(wc -l)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "simplest", but for me the simplest solution is:

```
command1 | awk '1; END { print "\ntotal number of lines:", NR }'
```

Comment: Actually this one works: `ls -l | awk '1; END { print "Total number of lines:", NR }'` . I'd still would like to know how to really synchronise tee output streams...

Answer (score 1):

Using process substitution:

```
command1 | tee >(wc -l)
```

Or, for appending the *Total number of files generated* prefix:

```
(command1 && printf "Total number of files generated: ") | tee >(wc -l)
```

Reference:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-can-i-send-stdout-to-multiple-commands

Comment: Hmm, maybe not `wait` but rather 2>&1 or 3>&1 ? What do you think?

Comment: @PawelDebski Not sure what would work best for you, but check this out:  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489139/bash-process-substitution-and-syncing