# How to make R script takes input from pipe and user given parameter

Tags: linux, r, bash, unix, stdin

I have the following R script (`myscript.r`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
dat <- read.table(file('stdin'), sep=" ",header=FALSE)
# do something with dat
# later with user given "param_1"
```

With that script we can run it the following way;

```
$ cat data_no_*.txt | ./myscript.r
```

What I want to do is to make the script takes additional parameter from user:

```
$ cat data_no_*.txt | ./myscript.r param_1
```

What should I do to modify the `myscript.r` to accommodate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For very basic usage, have a look at `?commandArgs`.

For more complex usage, two popular packages for command-line arguments and options parsing are [getopt](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/getopt/index.html) and [optparse](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optparse/index.html). I use them all the time, they get the job done. I also see [argparse](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/argparse/index.html), [argparser](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/argparser/index.html), and [GetoptLong](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GetoptLong/index.html) but have never used them before. One I missed: Dirk recommended that you look at [docopt](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/docopt/index.html) which does seem very nice and easy to use.

Finally, since you seem to be passing arguments via pipes you might find this [`OpenRead`()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15785789/1201032) function useful for generalizing your code and allowing your arguments to be pipes or files.

---

I wanted to test `docopt` so putting it all together, your script could look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

## Command-line parsing ##

'usage: my_prog.R [-v -m <msg>] <param> <file_arg> 

options:
 -v        verbose
 -m <msg>  Message' -> doc

library(docopt)
opts <- docopt(doc)

if (opts$v) print(str(opts)) 
if (!is.null(opts$message)) cat("MESSAGE: ", opts$m)

## File Read ##

OpenRead <- function(arg) {
   if (arg %in% c("-", "/dev/stdin")) {
      file("stdin", open = "r")
   } else if (grepl("^/dev/fd/", arg)) {
      fifo(arg, open = "r")
   } else {
      file(arg, open = "r")
   }
}

dat.con <- OpenRead(opts$file_arg)
dat <- read.table(dat.con, sep = " ", header = FALSE)

# do something with dat and opts$param
```

And you can test running:

```
echo "1 2 3" | ./test.R -v -m HI param_1 -
```

or

```
./test.R -v -m HI param_1 some_file.txt
```

Comment: What you *really* want to look at is the much smarter [dococt](http://cran.r-project.org/package=doctopt) package --- but then you *still* need a program to read them with, and `r` beats `Rscript` in my book ...

Comment: Fixed link: [docopt](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/docopt/index.html). Interesting indeed, mostly from an ease-of-use. But at a glance, I feel it doesn't have as many bells and whistles.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo.  I luuuv docopt after years of getopt (and related C/C++ libs).

Answer (score 2):

We built [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) to support just that via its `r` executable.

Have a look at its examples, it may fit your bill.